# Como pegar versão da minha aplicação?

Tags: c++, delphi

Preciso de uma maneira de pegar a versão da minha aplicação no **C++ Builder**, para colocar no *Caption* de um `TLabel`, que será exibido junto a uma tela inicial de apresentação do sistema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semelhante a sua pergunta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940707/how-do-i-programatically-get-the-version-of-a-dll-or-exe-file).

Mas como se trata de Delphi, uso uma função que funciona tanto no Builder quanto no Delphi:

```
function GetAppVersion: string;
var
  Versao: LongRec;
begin
  Versao:= LongRec(GetFileVersion(ParamStr(0)));
  Result := Format('%d.%d', [Versao.Hi, Versao.Lo])
end;
```

Para usar basta receber o resultado da função `GetAppVersion` no Caption do componente.

Onde:

```
Versao.Hi = Major Version
Versao.Lo = Minor Version
```